# Auto loading data from server to android application when have new data

Tags: android, json

I'm making an android application and a server where I store all data. In my app have an activity call "Meetings". The app will load a json each time when I run that activity.

But I just want the app load json at the first time open the app. After that the app should load json when have new meeting.

My question is:

- Is there anyway to do it? If have how is the app know when is the time to load data from server?

Sorry if my question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a few options here to do this:

1. WebSockets (HTML 5), if your web api is based off of .NET MVC you could look at signalR and the android library called signalA. You can look at also something based off socket.IO and Node.JS if you are running anything other than .NET
2. GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) push notification to tell the handset to pull a new update.
3. XMPP server, now this is a heavy option as you will need SMACK or aSMACK, as well as an XMPP server. this is how basically GCM works now. I would recommend this only if you are going to ever add messaging to the app.

I personally have used XMPP as my app also had a chat room as well for real time collaboration. I just extended the Message XML with a custom XML stanza in it.  I would personally recommend looking into WebSockets or GCM. Now all three of the options require you to have access to the source of the API to implement the changes. If you search around here on SO you should see some examples of web sockets and APIs that you can use.

Comment: I just want my app know when to load data from server and in my case is when the server have new data added. So, What is the best for me?

Comment: What language is your API in?

Comment: I'm using ruby on rails for server.

Comment: If your not too worried about server load, I think sockets, might be the best option. If you would prefer that the clients disconnect between gets, then I would look at gcm, realize there could be a slight delay with gcm, I have seen 30 seconds or more sometimes depending on the users connection.